# PHP login script works on XAMPP and one hosting site, but not when uploaded to Godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I have made this login page that works fine **[HERE](http://alex.mayo.yoobee.net.nz/goodday/admin_login.php)**.

If you try logging in with any credentials, it will say wrong `username` and `password`, which is correct. But when I uploaded the exact same code to Godaddy hosting, it doesn't work.

I'm 95% sure it's set up correctly with the database because the shop is using the same database and the shop is working fine.

And **[HERE](http://agooddaystore.com/admin_login.php)** is the exact same page, but I changed the hosting to Godaddy.

By the way, this is my first time uploading a site to a hosting by myself, so I could have easily missed some set up setting that I don't know about.

**This is my code for admin login:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])){
    $db = new database_manager();
    $username = $_POST['user_name']; //getting username from form
    $username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // making sure string is clean 

    $user_input_password = $_POST['password']; //getting password that user has imputted from form
    $real_password = $db->get_password($username);
    $verified = $db->compare_passwords($user_input_password, $real_password);
    //if they match take user to admin page

    if ($verified){
        $session =  new session_manager();
        $session->update_admin_session();
        header("location: ./admin.php");
    }
    else{
        echo ("<h1 id='reject'>Wrong Username or Password!</h1>");
    }
}
```

**this is the password verifier function part:**

```
public function get_password($username){
    $real_password = "";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username ='$username'";// sql statment for getting password that matches username
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    //getting password from database
    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $real_password = $row["password"];
    }
    return $real_password; //sending the real password back to be compared with the password the user input
}

//comparing user password to password on database
public function compare_passwords ($user_input_password,$real_password){
    $compare = password_verify($user_input_password , $real_password);
    return $compare;
}
```

The code and the databases are exactly the same for both sites.

Any help or comments/advice are most welcome.
Cheers XD

Comment: It is giving a 500 server error, if you look in the logs on the godaddy server, it will tell you what the problem is. At a guess I would say a path is different.

Comment: i cant find my error logs do u know how? :(

Answer (score 0):

> But when I uploaded the exact same code to Godaddy hosting, it doesn't
>   work.

did you check mysql connection or env settings?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("111.111.1.1", "sampleuser", "samplepassword", "sampledb");
```

or

```
# DB Settings
DB_CONFIG=mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=pass123
```

Answer (score 0):

check file permission after deployment on go daddy server.

Comment: how do i do this?